# How do I detect lowercase keys using the Keys enum in C#?

Tags: c#, xna, key

```
for (Keys k = Keys.A; k <= Keys.Z; k++)
{
    if (KeyPress(k))
        Text += k;
}
```

This code detects the key buttons I pressed in my keyboard and it will print out what key is pressed in the console. However, I pressed 'a' on the keyboard but it comes out as 'A'. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you check `Keys.Modifiers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your provided code, it should be a simple modification:

```
[...]
for (Keys k = Keys.A; k <= Keys.Z; k++)
{
  if (KeyPress(k))
  {
      if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) || keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift)) //if shift is held down
          Text += k.ToString().ToUpper(); //convert the Key enum member to uppercase string
      else
          Text += k.ToString().ToLower(); //convert the Key enum member to lowercase string
  }
}
[...]
```

Comment: Hi, how do I check for caplock activate/not activated?

Comment: Note that instead of looping over each key every frame, you can also loop through `keyboardState.GetPressedKeys()`.

Answer (score 9):

This is an often encountered problem. The trouble is that XNA isn't geared towards getting textual input from a keyboard. It's geared towards getting the current state of each key on the keyboard.

While you could write custom code to check things like whether shift is held down etc, what about keyboards that aren't the one you're using (e.g. different language, different layout). What most people do is get windows to do it for you.

If you want text to appear as expected you need to basically re-create a few things and get windows to do it for you.

See Promit's post here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/457783-xna-getting-text-from-keyboard/

Usage:

Add his code to your solution. Call `EventInput.Initialize in your game's`Initialize` method and subscribe to his event:

```
EventInput.CharEntered += HandleCharEntered;

public void HandleCharEntered(object sender, CharacterEventArgs e)
{
    var charEntered = e.Character;
    // Do something with charEntered
}
```

---

Note: If you allow any character to be inputted (e.g. foreign ones with umlauts etc.) make sure your `SpriteFont` supports them! (If not, maybe just check your font supports it before adding it to your text string or get the spritefont to use a special 'invalid' character).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm just doing a simple chat system with C# for my coursework. So I'm using a standard english US keyboard. I just need the upper casing and lower casing to work properly. Is there any sample code? I have read the Promit Post but I dont understand. I'm quite new to C#.

Comment: Here's my class which does the chatting thing

Comment: Can I ask after I copied "public class CharacterEventArgs" into my solution explorer, what should I add into my chatting class (TextEntry.cs) for it to work?

Comment: Put all the classes in your solution, not just the `CharacterEventArgs`, then as he says in the post, call `InputEvent.Initialize` in your `Game. Initialize ` method and subscribe to the `CharEntered` event.

Comment: @user1002229: Updated my answer, see my comment above.